# vba run-time error 91: Find date in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba script I wrote in excel that has run quite happily up until a few days ago when it became temperamental.  I have four worksheets that have named ranges, I am copying the name range, and pasting into a column that has todays date.  This macro fails on the second date lookup (`Sheet2`) and then on (`Sheet4`)

If I try to run it again it seems to fail then on all date lookups.
This code even had a brief realisation of what to do and executed with no errors only to then go back to errors on a rerun.

I get the

> run-time error 91: Object variable or With block not set

What has confused me is this worked fine for the last year up to about a week ago. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

Range("Sheet1").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C2").Select

Range("Sheet2").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C2").Select

Range("Sheet3").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("C2").Select

Range("Sheet4").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("C2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like the Find() is not making a match, and so the rest of the line fails.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes - I have tried creating a new excel workbook, creating a new sheet and duplicating the sheets  (thinking perhaps the workbook was corrupt)  with the same dates  between worksheetsand it still fails on finding the date for sheet2.  If I change the word date to "9/11/2018" it works.

Comment: Something is off on Sheet2 - are the dates really dates, or text?

Answer (score 1):

When using `Find()` it's more robust to check you got a match before trying to do something with that match.

E.g:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim f As Range, nm

    For Each nm In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

        Set f = Worksheets(nm).Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Worksheets(nm).Range("A1"), _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            With Range("Sheet1")
                f.Offset(4, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Date not found on '" & nm & "'"
        End If

    Next nm

End Sub
```

Comment: The sheets have exact same formatting and data as I highlighted the four sheets while creating all the data in the sheet for testing purposes.    
What I have just tried is within the macro moving the Sheet execution around so Sheet2, 1, 4, 3.  It fails on every second sheet, (currently now sheet 1 and sheet 3)

Comment: Your code works perfectly :)  No errors and find all the dates... I wonder if it is due to using Dim and Set